# Can I see how many generations I've gone through?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I tend to go through generations *very* quickly, and it's already built up to the point where counting manually isn't really feasible any more. Is there anywhere that there's a count of how many generations I've gone through?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I knew but I don't.  I'm surprised the game doesn't show the information on the current character's card (pause, X if using a 360 controller) though.  My current character's card says "1/6" in the bottom right; I wonder if there is a way to turn the page so to speak?

Comment: @peacedog The "1/6" in the bottom right of the card is your "power/toughness", in the style of Magic the Gathering. What that means is that your character deals relatively little damage but is extremely durable.

Comment: awesome, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way that you can get a quick count of how many times you died(or generations) is to beat the game. It will give you a "total children" and "total time". Example:

Total Children: XXXX
Total Time: XX:XX

Answer (score 12):

There is an easy way to get a good estimate.  The age of each character is a uniformly random number between `18-30` inclusive *(learned by viewing the source-code, it's in `RogueCastle.LineageObj.LineageObj()`)*, meaning the average age is `24`.

The first character starts in the year `700`.  Thus, if you take the year your last character died *(which you can see in the character-selection screen)*, subtract 700, and divide by 24, you will get the approximate number of generations you've gone through so far.

[image: My lineage]
*(My last character died in 3393.  `(3393-700)/24 ≈ 112`, so I've had approximately 112 generations.  The actual number, obtained by counting, is 111)*